# working with "_" in program-o aiml

Tags: php, aiml

I am trying to implement an aiml file in program-o but "_" doesn't seem to work as defined in the documentation.

The program version is 2.4.7.

```
<category>
    <pattern> _ action</pattern>
    <template> action </template>
</category>
```

Input:  "what is an action"

Expected output: action

Output: null (blank output)

Can anyone please explain how to work around this ?